# Delete data from a collection after 30 minutes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can i delete data from a collection in mongo db, to create the schemes I used mongoose.
How can I delete the date after 30 minutes, this is my code.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const validator = require('validator');

 const sessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
firstName:{
    type:String,
    required:[true,'First name is required!!!']        
},
lastName:{
    type:String,
    required:[true,'Last name is required!!!']
},
email:{
    type:String,
    unique:true,
    lowercase:true,
    required:[true,'Email adress is required!!!'],
    validate:[validator.isEmail,'Email adress is incorrect!!!']
},
password:{
    type:String,
    required:[true,'Password is required!!!'],
    minlength:8,
    select:false
},
passwordConfirm:{
    type:String,
    required:[true,'Please confirm your password'],
    validate:{
        validator:function(el){
            return el === this.password;
        }
    },
      message:"Password's are not the same!"
   },
acountToken:String,
accountConfirmToken:String,
accountConfirmTokenExpires:Date,


});



 const Session = mongoose.model('Session',sessionSchema);

 module.exports = Session;
```

I read something about Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/ but I dont undestood how to  useor if possible to use TTL index.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `expires` option in schema options for a date column, see [Schema date options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schemadateoptions_SchemaDateOptions)